# separate even and odd elements of list haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to separate elements of a list into to further lists, one for the odd and one for even numbers.

For Example,

```
input: [1,2,3,4,10]
output: ([2,4,10],[1,3])

sepList :: [Int]->([Int],[Int])
sepList [] = ([],[])
sepList (x:xs) | (x mod 2) ==0 = (([x],[]) ++ sepList xs) 
               | (x mod 2) /=0 = (([],[x]) ++ sepList xs)
               | otherwise = ([],[])
```

It gives error on `...++ sepList xs`
anyone could guide me here?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: FYI: `import Data.List (partition)` then `partition even [1..10]` does the same.

Comment: Note that the `otherwise` is only necessary to avoid a warning with `-Wall`; ``x `mod` 2`` is either 0 or it isn't, so the `otherwise` guard will never be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator`++` is used to concatenate 2 lists and neither of your arguments to `++` is a list,

```
([x],[]) ++ sepList xs
```

both `([x],[])` and `sepList xs` are pairs of lists. So what you want is to pattern match on `sepList xs` e.g. using a `let` binding,

```
let (ys,zs) = sepList xs in
```

and then return,

```
(x:ys,zs)
```

Answer (score 4):

You aren't concatenating two lists; you want to add a single element *to* a list, selected from the tuple output of the recursive call. Don't use `(++)`; use `(:)`.

```
sepList (x:xs) = let (evens, odds) = sepList xs
                 in if even x 
                    then (x:evens, odds)
                    else (evens, x:odds)
```

More simply, though, `sepList = partition even`. (`partition` can be found in `Data.List`.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers so far which suggest basically doing this by hand (by pattern-matching on the result of the recursive call), but there is actually an operator already defined for the types that you're working with that does exactly what you want! Lists form a monoid with `(<>) = (++)`, but you don't have two lists: you have two *pairs* of lists. Happily, the type of pairs are also a monoid if each element of the pair is a monoid: `(a,b) <> (c,d) = (a <> c, b <> d)`. So, you can simply replace your `++` call with `<>`, which will result in concatenating the corresponding lists in your pairs.

Comment: Isn't there a slight issue with thunks piling up by using `[x] <> stuff` instead of `x:stuff`?

Comment: We're building it like  `([x] <> ([y] <> ([z] <> [])))`, right? When the left list is short, that immediately resolves into `(x : ([] <> (...)))`, so I think it should be basically the same, besides the one wasted pattern-match to handle `[]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @chepner, I don't think that should be a significant problem. But I think the strictness of `<>` for pairs will be problematic if the list is very long. You could patch that up with `(a,b) <> (fst cd, snd cd)`, but by then you have a mess.

Comment: @amalloy No, I just don't have a good feel for what is and is not a space leak. @dfeuer Why would it be problematic? (I'm not being rhetorical; I'm just missing the subtleties involved here.) Where did `cd` come from, are you assuming `(a,b) <> cd`, so you want to delay `a<>c` (or rather, `a <> fst cd`) until you actually traverse the list of tuples?

Comment: @chepner, `cd` is the result of the recursive call. We don't want to perform it until we need to. `partition even (repeat 0) = (repeat 0, _|_)`, `partition even (repeat 1) = (_|_, repeat 1)`, and `partition even [1..] = ([0,2..], [1,3..])`.

Comment: @dfeuer why was `<>` made strict in the instance for tuples? it seems like a pretty bad  idea... there's strict tuples if people want to use them.

Comment: @JorgeAdriano, it's not strict in their contents; only in their structure. I think the definition is pretty natural as it is, but there's often tension like this in tuple instances. For example, `fmap` is strict (obeying `fmap id = id`) while `bimap` is lazy (obeying the weaker `bimap id id >= id`).

Comment: @JorgeAdriano, for whatever it's worth, I tend to prefer the stricter instances for tuples while Ed Kmett tends to prefer the lazier ones. I stand on the laws, and the fact that I generally want to be explicit about where I'm relying on laziness. Ed goes by the fact that it's easier and more convenient to strictify these particular things than to lazify them. There's no one right answer that will satisfy everyone, which is a bit sad.

Comment: @dfeuer I understand it's just HNF.  But not only will  `p <> ⊥` fail needlessly, for any  `p <> q` reducing `q` to HNF means performing some computation that may not be needed. Now consider a `foldr (<>)`. Regarding the definition being natural, difference would just be the `~` in the pattern matching...

Comment: @JorgeAdriano, for `<>`, you may be right, specifically *because* it's only HNF anyway. For non-degenerate underlying `Semigroup` instances you likely only lose a constant factor in space complexity. But hidden laziness tends to put me off.

Comment: @dfeuer nevermind what I said about "strict tuples" before though, indeed that is irrelevant here. But yes the point is, you can easily indicate when you want strictness. But if the operators are strict the reverse is much more complicated. Furthermore the language is lazy by default, it seems to be swimming against the tide and adding needless confusion.

Comment: As JorgeAdriano, the language has lazy bindings and lazy function application, but strict pattern matching (except for *outermost* patterns in pattern bindings, which I consider a design flaw). On this spectrum, you follow ekmett and I follow tibbe; there are plenty of heavyweights to agree with each of us.

Comment: That is a fair point, those design choices are inconsistent. This just reminded me of the the strictness "bug" that has [affected `partition` in ghc`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maintaining_laziness#Strict_pattern_matching_in_a_recursion) before. The accidental strictness here has the same effect (makes it fail for streams). But you do raise a good point. There should be some convention in libraries though...

Answer (score 1):

For enthusiasts, following one line will also work for separating list in even and odd.

```
sepList xs = (filter even xs , filter odd xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  import Data.List

  sepList :: [Int]->([Int],[Int])
  sepList = partition even

  sepList [1,2,3,4,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would use an `accumulator` to create the tuple containing the two lists.In our case the `accumulator` is `([],[])`.

```
split::[Int]->([Int],[Int])
split ls= go  ([],[]) ls where 
   go accu [] = accu
   go (odd,even) (x:xs) | x `mod` 2==0 = go (x:odd,even) xs
                        | otherwise = go (odd, x:even) xs
```

As you can see the elements need to be reversed since we are pushing on top of our lists with the `:` operator.

I do not know if this is optimal but i would write it like this with `reverse`:

```
module Split where
split::[Int]->([Int],[Int])
split ls=let rev tupl=(reverse . fst $ tupl ,reverse .snd $ tupl) in 
             rev $  go ([],[]) ls where 
                    go accu [] = accu
                    go (odd,even) (x:xs) | x `mod` 2==0 = go (x:odd,even) xs
                                         | otherwise = go (odd, x:even) xs
```